# In a top down 3d game, how can I simulate snow without actually covering entire world in the particle system?

Tags: unity

I am making a city builder, which has the classic camera features of any other city builder, move around, zoom, rotate, etc.

The problem Im facing atm is with snow. Snow falls really slowly, so if I make my snow vfx follow my camera and set it to "world" space, the camera outruns the snow (i.e there is no snow in the view for a few seconds until the vfx catches up) unless I make the vfx cover the entire world, which would be horrible for performance.

If I set the snow vfx to "local space" it just looks awful since the snow particles then actually follows the camera.

Is there some solution to this I'm missing where I can use a smaller bounds vfx to save on performance, while still keeping snow in camera view at all times?

Comment: As I write this I realized I can probably just activate/disable pre-warmed vfx across the map in chunks as the camera moves. I dont see any other way

Comment: That option sounds like it's worth trying, and posting as an answer if you find that it works for you.

Comment: It may also help to show a mock screenshot or example of what your ideal snow effect should look like in your game's perspective. Then answers can focus on ways to achieve that look.

Comment: @DMGregory chunks didnt really work. since they need to be pre-warmed it caused a huge spike when going between chunks. As for the type of snow, just the most basic, standard snowfall u can imagine, you can see an example of a simple snowfall here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wzubisvcyI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the easiest option was the one that worked best.

My issue at first was that I had the snow fall from a rectangle above the camera. When I changed it to a 200x200 box around the camera with volume spawning instead, it looks quite natural and now moves quite well with the camera.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it worked for you.